# What is the nth derivative of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find a general formula for the $n$th derivative of 
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}$$
I got up to,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  g^{(0)}(x) &=& g(x) \\
  g^{(1)}(x) &=& \dfrac{1}{(1 + x^2)^{1/2}} \\
  g^{(2)}(x) &=& \dfrac{-x}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}} \\
  g^{(3)}(x) &=& \dfrac{2x^2 - 1}{(x^2 + 1)^{5/2}} \\
  g^{(4)}(x) &=& \dfrac{-6x^3 + 9x}{(x^2 + 1)^{7/2}} \\
  g^{(5)}(x) &=& \dfrac{24x^4 - 72x^2 + 9}{(x^2 + 1)^{9/2}} \\
  g^{(6)}(x) &=& \dfrac{-120x^5 + 600x^3 - 225x}{(x^2 + 1)^{11/2}} \\
  g^{(7)}(x) &=& \dfrac{720x^6 - 5400x^4 + 4050x^2 -225}{(x^2 + 1)^{13/2}} \\
  g^{(8)}(x) &=& \dfrac{-5040x^7 + 52920x^5 - 66150x^3 + 11025x}{(x^2 + 1)^{15/2}} \\
 \end{eqnarray*}

Except for the first term in the numerator ($n!$), and the power in the denominator, I couldn't find a general pattern for the rest of the coefficients in the numerator. Could anyone shed me some light on this problem? Any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is this part of a Taylor Series question, I presume? Also, it seems like your derivatives are off by order $1$. What I mean is, the $0$th order derivative is just your original, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Comment: If this is part of finding the Maclaurin Series for your given function $g(x)$, you can use the well-known fact for the Maclaurin Series for a binomial expansion:

$$(1+x)^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {k\choose n}x^n = 1 + kx + \frac{k(k-1)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}x^3 + \cdots$$

In your case, 

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = (1+x^2)^{-1/2}$$

So, $k = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $x = x^2$ per the $(1+x)^k$ part.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks a lot. Yes, it's part of the Taylor series question.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684819/n-th-derivative-of-sinh-1-x/684852#684852

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is part of finding the  Maclaurin Series for your given function $g(x)$, you can use the well-known fact for the Maclaurin Series for a binomial expansion:

$$(1+x)^k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {k\choose n}x^n = 1 + kx + \frac{k(k-1)}{2!}x^2 + \frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!}x^3 + \cdots$$

In your case,

$$g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} = (1+x^2)^{-1/2}$$

So, $k = -\frac{1}{2}$ and $x = x^2$ per the definition of the expansion for $(1+x)^k$

If you need further help writing out the binomial expansion for your function, let me know and I'll fill in some more details.

Note that this **only** holds when our Taylor Series is about a point $a = 0$. That is, it is a Maclaurin Series. If $a \ne 0$, only then do we need to compute the nth order derivative about $a$. For a given Taylor Series, we can express a function $f$ as:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{N} \frac{f^n(a) (x-a)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I can't use Maclaurin Series fact. I still believe there must be a general formula for the $n$th derivative.

Comment: I'll try working out a formula for the $n$th order derivative then. Give me a few. What point $a$ is your series about?

Comment: $a = 0$, I've just figured it out based on your answer. Just plug  in $a = 0$, then the remain sequences is : -1, 1, 9, -225, 11025. Once again, thanks a bunch Joe.

Comment: For odd $n$, $g^{(n)}(0)=0$. For even $n=2k$, $g^{(n)}(0)=\frac{(-1)^{k}((2k)!)^2}{4^{k}(k!)^2}$. This is found by expanding $\binom{-1/2}{k}$ and using the fact that $1\cdot3\cdot\cdots\cdot(2k-1)=\frac{(2k)!}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot\cdots\cdot(2k)}$.

Comment: Ah, nice catch, Alex. Good work.