# n-th derivative of $\sinh^{-1} x$

Tags: derivatives

What is the n-th derivative of $\sinh^{-1} x$ ?

---

I have been able to prove  that it is $p_n(x)(x^2+1)^{-n-1/2}$, where $p_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$, and I have calculated it leading and constant coefficient, but I can't figure out the rest.

Another similar topic is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246144/what-is-the-nth-derivative-of-dfrac1-sqrt1-x2) .

Answer (score 1):

Use the function $f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{x+1}}$ and $g(x)=x^2$.
The derivatives of order $n\geq1$ of $f$ and $g$ are 
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!(x+1)^{n+1/2}},\quad g^{(n)}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}2x&\text{if $n=1$}\\2&\text{if $n=2$}\\0&\text{otherwise.}\end{array}\right.$$

You can now use the formula of Arbogast (better known under the name of [Faà di Bruno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula)) which gives the $n^\text{th}$ derivative of the composed function $f\circ g$:
$$ (f\circ g)^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{\substack{m_1,\dots,\,m_n\\m_1+2m_2+\cdots+nm_n=n}}\frac{n!}{m_1!\,\dots\,m_n!}f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\;\cdot\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{g^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}.$$
In this case, the right-hand product is simply $(2x)^{m_1}$ if $m_k=0$ for $k>2$ and $0$ otherwise. As a conclusion you get 
$$\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=
\sum_{m_1,m_2\,| m_1+2m_2=n}\frac{n!}{m_1!m_2!}\frac{(-1)^{m_1+m_2}(2m_1+2m_2)!}{4^{m_1+m2}(m_1+m_2)!}\frac{(2x)^{m_1}}{(x^2+1)^{m_1+m_2+1/2}}.$$

The sum rewrites as a simple sum, in a way depending on the parity of $n$. 
I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Maple code $$diff(arcsinh(x), x$ n) $$ produces $${\frac {{2}^{n-1}
G^{1, 3}_{3, 3}\left({x}^{2}\, \Big\vert\,^{0, 1/2, 1/2}_{0, -1/2+n/2, n/2}\right)
{x}^{1-n}}{\sqrt {\pi }}}
 .$$ See [MeijerG](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MeijerG) for info.

PS. Because $\sinh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2}+1)$ and $$( \sinh^{-1}(x))'=\frac {1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+1}},$$ use the formulas  $$ \left(\frac f g \right)'= \frac {f'g-fg'}{g^2} $$ and 
$${\frac {d }{dx}} \left(  \left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{n/2
} \right)=\left( {x}^{2}+1 \right) ^{n/2-1}nx $$ and induction to this end.

Comment: Thank you, but I suppose that there is an elementary representation.